# How to update the current language with ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, electron, ngx-translate

I am using Electron 10 and Angular 10 and also use `ngx-translate`. I would like to update the translations of the current view/page after the user switched the language in a dropdown menu.

During development I use of course Angular with its HTTP server, that's why I use `HttpLoaderFactory`. But for production builds I use the custom `translateFactory` which loads the JSON files via `TranslateUniversalLoader`. Is this ok to do?

Neither in development nor production builds I can make the strings update without restarting the app. I have a dropdown menu and on change I simply call `this.translate.use(lang)`. Is the view supposed to be reloaded? What is the expected behaviour here?

I register the module as follows:

```
export class TranslateUniversalLoader implements TranslateLoader {
       
  constructor() {
  }

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
      return of(TRANSLATIONS[lang]);
    }
  }
  
  export function translateFactory() {
    return new TranslateUniversalLoader();
  }
}
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: isProductionBuild() ? translateFactory : HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate : false
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are calling `this.translate.use(lang)` from lazyload-like submodules that are not injected into the root module where `TranslateModule` is imported. To call it from the lazyload modules, create a service named `LanguageService`:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LanguageService {
   language$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

   applyLang(lang: string) {
      this.language$.next(lang);
   }
}
```

And watch `language$` change from `app.component.ts`:

```
...
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private languageService: LanguageService, private translate: TranslateService) {
      this.languageService.language$.subscribe(lang => {
          if (lang) {
              this.translate.use(lang); // Use lang here
          }
      });
   }
}
```

Now you can use LanguageService to change the language from any lazyloaded modules.

```
...
constructor(private languageService: LanguageService) {}

updateLanguage() {
   this.languageService.applyLang('en'); // Call from components belonging to lazyload modules
}
```

Otherwise, simplify the flow by calling translate.use from LanguageService directly.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LanguageService {
   constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

   applyLang(lang: string) {
      this.translate.use(lang);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your detailed answer! I think you are really onto something. I implemented everything as described (+ registration of `LanguageService`), and can confirm that `language$.subscribe` is called with the corresponding language. But still no update of the UI. Do you have an idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: I also use this library for my angular universal project. so i tried it quickly before writing this and confirmed it works. could you share the full app.module.ts with me?

Comment: I just realized I didn't all load languages properly :-o. You made my day! Any chance I can put a bounty on this answer?

Comment: thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties is this one?

Comment: "Start a bounty" button is found below the question's comment area

Comment: I will add a bounty nontheless as soon as I can in the next days! Bounty belongs where it belongs.. :-)